# How to change color and size of plotly.express in Python?

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I'm using **plotly.express** to make a plot of my Artificial Neural Networks in Python.
I'll show my code:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(newDf, x="Glucose", y="Age", color="Outcome")
fig.show()
```

I would like the sidebar of "color" (comprehends the Outcome) has only 0 and 1 values (instead of 0, 0.2, 0.4...). Plus, I would like to change the color of the points in the scatter plot. Currently, the plot has blue(0) and yellow(1) points and, expecially the yellow ones, are difficult to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming your outcome only has 0 and 1 values, the easy way to make `plotly` treat it as a discrete value would be to convert it to a string.

```py
df["Outcome"] = df["Outcome"].astype(str) #convert to string

# you can convert back to numeric later, if needed
df["Outcome"] = df["Outcome"].astype(float)
```

Now, to change the colors you can use the argument `color_discrete_sequence` like this:

```py
mport plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(newDf, x="Glucose", y="Age", color="Outcome", 
                 color_discrete_sequence= ["blue", "red"])
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me.

Comment: No problem. You can mark the question as answered, If you feel like it is satisfactory .